# matlab 2015b java crash

Tags: java, crash, osx-yosemite

I get a Java crash whenever I do anything in Matlab 2015b in Yosemite :
such as opening Matlab.

There were patches issued for earlier Matlab releases, but nothing for 2015.

Please explain how to fix this?

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/johnknowles/Documents/MATLAB/OccfertSept2015.dtd (No such file or directory)
    at com.mathworks.project.impl.plugin.XmlReaderImpl.parseInput(XmlReaderImpl.java:138)
    at com.mathworks.project.impl.plugin.XmlReaderImpl.<init>(XmlReaderImpl.java:73)
    at com.mathworks.project.impl.plugin.PluginManager$2.read(PluginManager.java:161)
    at com.mathworks.project.impl.model.ProjectManager.getStandardProjectXml(ProjectManager.java:733)
    at com.mathworks.project.impl.model.ProjectManager$3.run(ProjectManager.java:580)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.FileDecorationModel$DeferHandler.run(FileDecorationModel.java:386)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.FileDecorationModel$2.get(FileDecorationModel.java:275)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.FileDecorationModel$1$2.run(FileDecorationModel.java:182)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.FileDecorationModel$DeferHandler.run(FileDecorationModel.java:386)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.FileDecorationModel$2.get(FileDecorationModel.java:275)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.util.UiFileSystemUtils.getDecorationSynchronously(UiFileSystemUtils.java:124)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.util.UiFileSystemUtils.getDecorationSynchronously(UiFileSystemUtils.java:97)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.table.FileSystemExpansionProvider.getDecoration(FileSystemExpansionProvider.java:130)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.table.FileSystemExpansionProvider.getDecoration(FileSystemExpansionProvider.java:135)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.table.IconColumn$1.convert(IconColumn.java:37)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.explorer.model.table.IconColumn$1.convert(IconColumn.java:34)
    at com.mathworks.widgets.grouptable.GroupingTableColumn.getValue(GroupingTableColumn.java:149)
    at com.mathworks.widgets.grouptable.GroupingTableRow.getValueAt(GroupingTableRow.java:471)
    at com.jidesoft.grid.TreeTableModel.getValueAt(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2717)
    at com.jidesoft.grid.JideTable.getValueAt(Unknown Source)
    at com.jidesoft.grid.CellSpanTable.getValueAt(Unknown Source)
    at com.jidesoft.grid.JideTable.prepareRenderer(Unknown Source)
    at com.jidesoft.grid.CellStyleTable.prepareRenderer(Unknown Source)
    at com.mathworks.widgets.grouptable.GroupingTableUIDelegate.paintCell(GroupingTableUIDelegate.java:65)
    at com.mathworks.widgets.grouptable.GroupingTableUIDelegate.paintSpanCells(GroupingTableUIDelegate.java:372)
    at com.mathworks.widgets.grouptable.GroupingTableUIDelegate.paint(GroupingTableUIDelegate.java:140)
    at com.jidesoft.plaf.basic.BasicCellSpanTableUI.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:779)
    at com.jidesoft.grid.CellStyleTable.paintComponent(Unknown Source)
    at com.mathworks.widgets.grouptable.GroupingTable.paintComponent(GroupingTable.java:277)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1055)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:888)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1064)
    at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:731)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:888)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1064)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:888)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1064)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:888)
    at javax.swing.JSplitPane.paintChildren(JSplitPane.java:1047)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1064)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:888)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1064)
    at com.mathworks.mde.explorer.Explorer.paint(Explorer.java:1077)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5232)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1529)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1452)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1249)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5180)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4991)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:808)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:796)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:796)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:769)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:718)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(RepaintManager.java:62)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1677)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:738)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:699)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/johnknowles/Documents/MATLAB/OccfertSept2015.dtd (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.mathworks.project.impl.plugin.XmlReaderImpl.parseInput(XmlReaderImpl.java:125)
    ... 74 more
```

Comment: The answer is in the first line of the execption. You are missing this file `/Users/johnknowles/Documents/MATLAB/OccfertSept2015.dtd` (No such file or directory)`

Comment: Thanks David. I should have added that there were no such files in previous versions of Matlab (2013, 2014), so I need to figure out what is missing that is assumed in the new Matlab (2015b). I suspect that there is an incompatibility of some sort between the Java version that comes with Matlab and the OS version, but that is already stretching my understanding; I feel that I can go no further without expert advice.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't use Matlab or OSX so I can't help any further :/

Comment: Is that where you installed MATLAB? I think it got stuck somewhere. Try creating an empty file with that name and see what happens.